# Clearing css applied by jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a routine to move elements (pages of a magazine) out of the way using jquery animation:

```
$this.animate({right:"100%"},1200,'easeOutBounce',function(){
   $this.addClass('hidden').removeClass('remove');
   var t = setTimeout( "$this.css( 'left','' ).css( 'right','' ).removeClass( 'remove' )",1200);
   }
        });
```

The activation of this does not always clear these variables, making consecutive visits to this page awkward, because it sometimes still have a css value of right:100%

I have also tried separating it using a separate function:

```
$this.animate({right:"100%"},1000,'easeOutBounce',function(){
                        doneShuffling($this);
                        })

function doneShuffling(element) {
   element.removeClass('remove').addClass('hidden').css('left','').css('right','');
}
```

The problem I am having is that the css is not being removed, nor is the 'remove' class. This function is driven by clicking on a panel on the left and right to go through the site, and multiple clicks in a short time seems to confuse the behaviour of the script.

You can visit the site here: http://straathof.acadnet.ca/reblend50.4 (sorry, the script is a dog's breakfast) and there is a console-log in place to indicate what is happening and where. The second script can be seen at http://straathof.acadnet.ca/reblend50.5

I have tried to limit only one animation in the past but the people using it don't like the enforced pauses. And on the ipad, because you can click left and right quickly, you sometimes get invisible pages due to the visible pages having right:100% or left:100%.

Any help would be appreciated... When finished this script is intended to be used in an open source project.

Comment: you could try doneShuffling($(this));. Not sure what $this really is. Normally would either be "this" plain javascript or $(this) jquery style

Comment: I saw it used in a previous project and thought it was commonplace. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing about adding css rules is that it won't remove them, so your best bet might be to just completely clear out the style attribute. I tested it and it didn't seem to cause any problems (the height and width are added back).

Then after looking at your script a bit more, I tried optimizing it a bit. Basically the left and right code is mostly repeated. And the `swipeBusy` variable isn't really needed if you check the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/). Here is what I ended up with:

```
/*****************************************
***
*** New Page is on the left - used only for non webkit
***
******************************************/

function newPageSides(newPage, dir){ // dir true = right, false = left
    $remover =  $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage + ')');
    if (!$remover.is(':animated')){
        prevPage = currentPage;
        $remover.attr('style','').removeClass('remove');
        if (newPage>0) {
            currentPage = newPage;
        } else {
            currentPage = prevPage + (dir ? 1 : -1);
        }
        if (currentPage > maxPage){
            currentPage = maxPage;
        } else if (currentPage < 0){
            currentPage = 0;
        } else {
            $adder = $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage + ')');
            $adder.removeClass('hidden').addClass('active').attr('style','');
            $remover =  $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + prevPage + ')');
            $remover.addClass('remove').removeClass('active');
            d = (dir) ? { right:'100%' } : { left:'100%' };
            $remover.animate(d, 1200, 'easeOutBounce',function(){
                $remover
                    .addClass('hidden')
                    .attr('style', '')
                    .removeClass('remove');
            });
        }
        newPage = 0;
        $('.active').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}

function newPageLeft(newPage){
    newPageSides(newPage, false);
}

/*****************************************
***
*** New Page is on the Right - used only for non webkit
***
******************************************/

function newPageRight(newPage){
    newPageSides(newPage, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimization. I've spent too much time on this project to notice when things could be leaner. If you watch using a web inspector, you will notice that not all of the 'remove' classes are being changed to 'hidden', so the $remover being used in the callback for the animation is whatever is current at the time.

 
I may try putting the animation in a separate function so it gets a specific variable to use internally and see if that works.

Comment: You can see how it works live here: [http://straathof.acadnet.ca/reblend55/](http://straathof.acadnet.ca/reblend55/)

Answer (score 0):

Placing the animation in a separate function worked. The 'remove' classes are all changed to 'hidden' classes properly, and a minimum number of articles are present at any time (important on ios devices because each visible element requires memory.)

```
/*****************************************
***
*** Check for NewPageSides with newpage and direction
***
******************************************/
function newPageSides(newPage, dir){ // dir true = right, false = left
    $remover =  $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage + ')');
    if (!$remover.is(':animated')){
        prevPage = currentPage;
        $remover.attr('style','').removeClass('remove');
        if (newPage>0) {
            currentPage = newPage;
        } else {
            currentPage = prevPage + (dir ? 1 : -1);
        }
        if (currentPage > maxPage){
            currentPage = maxPage;
        } else if (currentPage < 0){
            currentPage = 0;
        } else {
            $adder = $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + currentPage + ')');
            $adder.removeClass('hidden').addClass('active').attr('style','');
            $remover =  $('.article-wrapper:eq(' + prevPage + ')');
            $remover.addClass('remove').removeClass('active');
            d = (dir) ? { right:'100%' } : { left:'100%' };

            animateSlide($remover)
        }
        newPage = 0;
        $('.active').removeClass('hidden');
        //$('.remove').removeClass('remove').addClass('hidden');
    }
}

/*****************************************
***
*** Animate tht puppy!
***
******************************************/

function animateSlide(currentSlide){
    currentSlide.animate(d, 1200, 'easeOutBounce',function(){

                currentSlide
                    .addClass('hidden')
                    .attr('style', '')
                    .removeClass('remove');
            });
}

/*****************************************
***
*** New Page is on the left - used only for non webkit
***
******************************************/

function newPageLeft(newPage){
    newPageSides(newPage, false);
}

/*****************************************
***
*** New Page is on the Right - used only for non webkit
***
******************************************/

function newPageRight(newPage){
    newPageSides(newPage, true);
}
```